# Random variables with unkown distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be descrete indipendent random variables, $n\in\mathbb N$.
$\forall n\in\mathbb N$ the image of $X_n$ is $ \\{ x\in\mathbb N:-10\le x\le10 \\} $
$\forall n\in\mathbb N$ $E[X_n]=0$
Calculate an upper bound for $$P\left(\frac{1}{n}\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right\rvert\gt\frac{1}{10}\right)$$
I tried to use (unsuccessfully) both Markov's inequality and Chebishev's inequality.
Using Markov's inequality:
Let $X=\frac{1}{n}\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right\rvert$, then $0\le E[X]\le 10$, which is not useful.
Using Chebyshev's inequality:
Let $X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$, then $Var(X)\le \frac{100}{n}$, which is not useful.

Comment: Actually $Var(X) \le 100 /n$

Comment: @Alex_28 why do you say the $100/n$ bound on variance is not useful?

Comment: @Michael You're right, "not useful" is bit imprecise. What I meant is that using Chebyshev's inequality, $P\left(\left\lvert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right\rvert\gt\frac{1}{10}\right)\lt\frac{10000}{n}$ doesn't give a lot of information, at least for small values of $n$

Comment: "Calculate an approximation" I guess they mean a bound, right ?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, specifically an upper bound. My bad, I could have translated it better

Comment: You can use the Hoeffding inequality, but in general you will need large $n$ to make the bound small. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

Comment: I think Chebyshev is better than Hoeffding for $n \in \{10000, 13862\}$, but Hoeffding decreases exponentially fast.